# How to do PIVOT in SQL Server doing aggregation on multiple columns

Tags: sql-server, pivot-table

I am trying to use PIVOT in SQL Server to get data output in required format.

My current data looks like:

Source data:

```
+------------+---------+---------+-------+-----------+------------+
| CustomerID | SalesID | Product | Brand | SellPrice | Commission |
+------------+---------+---------+-------+-----------+------------+
| 1          | 1       | Mobile  | XYZ   | 600.00    | 60.00      |
| 1          | 1       | TV      | ABC   | 500.00    | 50.00      |
| 1          | 1       | Laptop  | ZXC   | 300.00    | 30.00      |
| 1          | 1       | Mobile  | XYZ   | 400.00    | 8.0        |
| 1          | 1       | Laptop  | ZXC   | 300.00    | 12.00      |
+------------+---------+---------+-------+-----------+------------+
```

Looking for query with PIVOT which will return following format data:

```
+------------+---------+-------------------------+---------------------+-------------------------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
| CustomerID | SalesID | Total_Mobile_Commission | Total_TV_Commission | Total_Laptop_Commission | Total_XYZ_Sell_Pric | Total_ABC_SellPrice | Total_ZXC_SellPrice |
+------------+---------+-------------------------+---------------------+-------------------------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
| 1          | 1       | 68.00                   | 50.00               | 42.00                   | 1000.00             | 500.00              | 600.00              |
+------------+---------+-------------------------+---------------------+-------------------------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
```

Comment: Can you please format your example data and query output as code? Edit your question, select the text and press the { } button abovethe text box

Comment: Thanks for the quick tips. I am first timer using Stackoverflow. Updated my question  with better formatting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't use the pivot keyword for this, but then I don't often use it for anything; I find the "grouped case when" method of pivoting easier to understand and more flexible:

```
SELECT
  CustomerID,
  SalesID,
  SUM(CASE WHEN product = 'mobile' then commission END) as Total_Mobile_Commission
  SUM(CASE WHEN product='tv' THEN comission END) as Total_TV_Commission,
  SUM(CASE WHEN product = 'laptop' THEN commission END) as Total_Laptop_Commission,
  SUM(CASE WHEN brand = 'xyz' THEN sellprice END as Total_XYZ_Sell_Pric,
  SUM(CASE WHEN brand = 'abc' THEN sellprice END) as Total_ABC_SellPrice,
  SUM(CASE WHEN brand = 'zxc' THEN sellprice END)  as Total_ZXC_SellPrice
FROM table
GROUP BY customerid, salesid
```

If you want more insight on how it works, run it without the group by and sum keywords so it doesn't do any aggregating(and add in the brand and product columns). You'll see your data spread out from being a 4 columnar form of product/brand/price/commission, into a column that contains only mobile commission or null, another column that contains only TV commission or null etc; 6 columns in total that are mostly null but do have a value whenever the brand or product is right for the name of the column.  Summing these brings it down to one line per customerid/salesid squishing all the nulls

Comment: Thanks for the code. It works like a charm. I was just trying to implement the same with multiple PIVOT statements and was not thought of CASE at all. Thanks for sharing the other away around.